# What is the best way to get data from server and store into database without interfering UI in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I am fetching city,state and product data from server using web service and storing it is in database using a separate thread respectively.

But when I try to access UI,it shows alert with app is not responding with Wait and close buttons on it.

```
              Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  public void run() {
                    try {

                        String res = "";
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        res = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                        threadMsg(res);

                    } catch (Throwable t) {

                        Log.i("test", "Thread  exception " + t);
                    }
                }

                     void threadMsg(String msg) {

                    if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
                        Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("message", msg);
                        msgObj.setData(b);
                        handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
                    }
                }


                Handler handler = new Handler() {

                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                        String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

                        if ((null != aResponse)) {

                         // stores data in database
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        // failed or empty response     
                        }    

                    }
                };

            });
      thread.start();
```

I have used separate thread for separate web service call.I have also tried with AsyncTask but result is the same.

So, What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: give us some code to understand

Comment: Are you trying to do UI operations from background threads? You should only touch the UI from the UI thread.... If you use AsyncTask you do that in the "post" method.

Comment: no I am not doing any UI operations from background threads,m just storing data in db.

Comment: if you doing the UI operations in the handler ,you can get the handler method out of the thread.put it in the Main thread.

Comment: AsyncTask is good for fetching small amount of data, but if you are fetching large amounts of data then you should use a service instead, they should always be used to perform long running background activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use services for this purpose.

You can follow these steps:

- Write a class that extends `IntentService`
- Add the service class in your `AndroidManifest` file
- In the `onHandleIntent` method of your service class, perform the action. In your case, you need to fetch data from server and store in database.
- When you want the action to be performed i.e in you `Activity`, create an `Intent` object and pass it to the `startService` method like this

**Sample Code:**
A Sample service class

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

    public HelloIntentService() {
        super("HelloIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // if additional parameters are sent, receive them in the following way
        Bundle bundle  = intent.getExtras();
        String parameter1 = bundle.getString("param1");
        int parameter2 = bundle.getInt("param2");

        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String res = "";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            res = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }

        // store data in database
    }
}
```

In your manifest file

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".HelloIntentService" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Sample activity code on how to call the service

```
public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    // call the service where you need
    private void myMethod(){
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, HelloIntentService.class);
        // you can send additional parameters this way
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("param1", "Sample Parameter Value");
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("param2", 100);
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

See details here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html

Comment: Thanks :) I'm also going to add a full code example

Comment: It will be more helpful.Thanks @Rafiqunabi :)

Comment: I've added sample code. Hope this will help. Also don't forget to accept my answer if it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for fetch data and storing it in database so that you  wont get any ANR

write your logic in `doInBackground ()`

you can use `onPostExecute(Result)` to notify ui else you can create custom callback